# Schengen visitor visa for parents

Tags: schengen, visa-refusals, switzerland, proof-provenance-of-funds

My father wants to visit me in Switzerland and plans to apply for a Schengen visa. My father doesn't receive any pension and is financially dependent on me. How should I convey this to the embassy? Because they will need a financial statement for his travel.

His application was rejected twice before with the following reasons.

> You have not provided proof of sufficient means of subsistence for the duration of intended stay

Even though 8 had deposited approximately 2 to 300,000 INR in his account.

Comment: It looks like a funds parking refusal. How did you deposit the money in his account? Do you send him regular amounts? Did the paperwork provided to support the application explain a) that you had provided the money; and b) show where you got it from?

Comment: Money parking? Never deposit money on an account just to show money. You must provide your bank account. If he is old, he is also not a risk he will remain to work. But you should provide that they are willing to return to origin country,

Comment: For how long was your father intending to visit? Did the amount you provided (funds parking concerns aside) meet the minimum level required for visitors to Switzerland?

Answer (score 3):

How to present this situation for a first-time application, if there are no refusals yet:

- Send him money for his living expenses regularly from your bank account to his bank account. Not in irregular sums.
- Submit statements for **both** accounts, and explain where **you** got the money from and that you can afford to send it.

How to handle your situation:

- Many visa appicants borrow money and "park" it on their account to make their finances look better. This money isn't theirs, they will have to repay it by overstaying and working illegally.
- After several refusals, it might be wise to get a specialized lawyer in Switzerland.